# Django Forms: Writing data to database

Tags: django, forms

[This doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/) explains how to gather form data for sending as mail. But, how can it be made to write the data to the database and made available in the admin interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest method would be to use [ModelForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) to create a form based on your model. Calling `form.save()` on that form will automatically save your data to the database.

If you created your form manually, you will have to manually populate a model instance and then call `.save()` on your model instance.

Comment: +1 I really wish I could up vote this answer more than once! Been searching for exactly this and nothing turned up... Thank you!